# How to remove gap between image and its border?

Tags: html, css

why is there a gap between image and it's border and how can I remove it?

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: solid #2ba272 3px;
}

body{
background-color:#f91880;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535713875002-d1d0cf377fde?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8MXw3NjA4Mjc3NHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" />
```

Comment: did you try margin: 0;?

Comment: I don't see any gaps (FF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by antialiasing at pixels that include the image and its border. The background colour is showing through for no good reason.

You can fix this by setting the background colour of your image to be the same as the border colour:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: solid #2ba272 3px;
  background-color:#2ba272;   /* <<< add this line <<< */
}

body{
  background-color:#f91880;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535713875002-d1d0cf377fde?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8MXw3NjA4Mjc3NHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" />
```

Answer (score 2):

add the image background color same as border color

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid #2ba272 1px;
    background: #2ba272;
}
```